# Changing jquery validation error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I'm using jQuery and the [minlength method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength#length) for the validation plugin

```
rules: {
       checkboxes: {
            required:true,
                minlength: 3
        }
            }
```

This works how i want it to, BUT the error message I'm getting is "Please enter at least 3 characters." How do I instead say, "Please check at least 3 boxes"?

in the validate.js file, minlength looks like

> minlength: $.format("Please enter at least {0} characters.")

Does it have something to do with the "$.format"? If not, how do I use this working method to create my own error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `rules`, do:

```
messages: {
    checkboxes: {
        minlength: 'Please check at least 3 boxes.'
    }
}
```

Comment: Others, don't forget to add the comma. I used this code and was stumped for a long time as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
messages: {checkboxes : {minlength: 'Please check at least 3 boxes'}}
```